# Is there any editor like jsfiddle available for local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an editor that works like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) on my local machine, without having to be connected to the internet.

Comment: What are your requirements? For example AJAX requests, etc, or simple markup (HTML/CSS, etc)?

Comment: "local machine"? jsfiddle's js is all local too. Local to browser. If you are looking for a *text editor like jsfiddle* then I think your best options are these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925219/best-javascript-editor-or-ide-with-intellisense-and-debugging-possibly

Comment: I would like a jsfiddle type editor/viewer for testing out my company's internal javascript/css libraries.

Comment: @Mike Perhaps you need something like http://www.jsexample.com ?

Comment: You should check out Adobe's free http://brackets.io/. It is a really nice html/js/css editor and it has a live preview feature. Also it is open source and has lots of useful plugins.

Comment: https://github.com/vinnizworld/code_editor is one good option, in addition to HTML, CSS, JS it can compile php as well.

Comment: Triplety By Flammy (Mac) 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/triplety-playground-for-web/id654989327
http://flammy.net/triplety/

Kodeweave (Win/Linux/Chrome App)
http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 18):

Check out Remy Sharp's [JSBin](https://github.com/remy/jsbin/). Installation instructions [here](https://github.com/remy/jsbin/wiki/How-to-install-JS-Bin-in-your-own-environment).

Comment: installing instructions are too complicated for me actually

Comment: Yeah, 2-years later and it's pretty hard to install... wish it were easier and PHP development was actively developed on still...

Comment: Installation is looking quite simple now: `npm install jsbin`

Comment: @nagytech - unfortunately not. I installed node.js from scratch, and based on warnings/errors I did: `npm install -g grunt, npm install -g grunt-contrib-uglify, npm install -g grunt-contrib-jshint, npm install grunt-contrib-concat --save-dev, npm install npm-install-peers`, finally I executed **npm install -g jsbin**  but still getting error, and it rolls back. Simple is different. What is wrong?

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 12):

You can create a plain text file, say `test.html`, then write your JavaScript and open the file in a browser.  If you want to reference any libraries, just download them to the same folder and reference them.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    alert("Hello World!");
    $("#foo").hide();
</script>

<div id="foo">
    Hello World
</div>
```

Or you can try something like [vimfiddler](https://github.com/codeape2/vimfiddler).

Comment: This should be correct answer!!!

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial shows how you can easily build your own using an iframe:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-inject-custom-html-and-css-into-an-iframe/

Comment: Thanks but that didn't answer my question.

Comment: Sorry about that. The solution allows you to enter html, css and JavaScript, and see the result, like jsfiddle. It just doesn't have all the bells and rings.

Comment: I wanted something a kind of executable, that i can download on my local machine

Comment: well, a Web page like this can run on your local machine.

Comment: I meant without Internet access. As long as you have a browser...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried writing code right in to firebug console ? to write/learn javascript it's best tool i know.

edit:
for html/css there's a lot of tools that might help (actually i sits on windows but there's no special app that might be useful), on mac there's coda or espresso which is typical (and not typical) wysywig tool and have live preview mode, as far as i know coda offers a cheap support of javascript.

for javascript firebug in firefox / developer tool in safari, chrome.

Answer (score 0):

on windows: 
Microsoft Web Expression 4.0 is available for HTML/CSS.  
there are extensions like code cola for chrome. Chrome's inspector tool is awesome too. you can also use Firebug in FireFox.

For jQuery, there are extensions for Google Chrome. with or without documentation. like jquery shell. jquery browser. For CSS there are extensions like code cola. 
though you will need web-server for extensions in chrome to work. like IIS. create a virtual directory in IIS for that.

Answer (score 0):

The only combination you need is this..

- [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) - For code editing
- [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) - As the rendering engine, i.e. to view your page
- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) - Ultimate DOM inspector

Comment: I am looking for something like an editor, which will have four components seperated like how jsfiddle behaves.Is there anything that combines all these 3 components that you mentioned into a single piece like jsfiddle

Comment: Don't take this as being smart but save (Cntl+S) in FlashDevelop, swap to Firefox (alt-tab), refresh (f5) and you're done! Rinse and repeat. Your desktop is basically tieing the 2 applications in together (firebug runs inside firefox) - plus you have the advantage of inspecting the DOM through Firebug (which jsfiddle doesn't have)