# native editor like jsfiddle

Tags: editor

I find jsfiddle very useful for client side web development. I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222554/is-there-any-editor-like-jsfiddle-available-for-local-machine) link, but it is not helpful. The features I want are:

1. screen split in 4 sections -HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and Result
2. Autocomplete
3. JSLint/JSHint

Is there such editor available, if not can we customize existing editor like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any offline tools like jsfiddle.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455667/are-there-any-offline-tools-like-jsfiddle-net)

Comment: You can try this one. https://github.com/vinnizworld/code_editor

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: mine was asked before the other one. So, technically, the other one is duplicate. But, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no editor with the result screen. That would need a browser environment for testing, which is rare in desktop editors.

I think there are some editors available with ecmascript support, allowing to execute/test tiny snippets of code. But I haven't seen any with a built-in or plugged-in browser.

I think it may be more promising to transform jsfiddle into an offline-browser-application. With javascripts file-IO this may suit better than online fiddle and offline editor.

Comment: But there are several editors that do connect to the browser: [Brackets](http://download.brackets.io) and [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) for example. And many IDEs have an integrated preview that you can view split next to your code, including [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/), [DreamWeaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html), [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/) and [Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36179).

Answer (score 2):

not sure about the 4-way split, but I like using http://liveweave.com

Answer (score 2):

[Lighttable](http://www.lighttable.com/) lets you edit and view Javascript,CSS, and HTML, and a browser result tab in multiple tabs, but only on a horizontal split, but still quite amazing.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if still interested, have a look at [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) and [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at http://fadul.net/code-editor/default.php
It's powerful and has many features that may match what you are looking for.